# Why are some bugs I'm affected by and subscribed to missing in my Launchpad bug list?

Tags: launchpad

I have a long list of bugs in my Launchpad account but some bugs I set to being affected by and being subscribed to are not showing up in that list. Even when I change the options of bugs to show I don't get these bugs. First I thought these were bugs being set to 'wishlist' but some of them are showing up in the list.

Does anyone else know that he/she is subscribed to a bug he/she doesn't find in his bug list? And maybe there's also someone who knows how to fix this.

Comment: I noticed that the other day myself. I thought I had forgotten to actually file the bug or something, though that seemed strange. Cool username, btw. :)

Comment: Some bugs are hidden by default, those that have been updated with the following statuses, "Invalid", "Won't Fix" or "Fix Released". They can still be viewed by doing an advanced search. [Launchpad Question #102604](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/102604)